# FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker, service worker already added

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, angularfire

Im new to Firebase cloud messaging .My Goal is to register a token so that i can send notifications. I went by the book. I added a service worker file in my root directory (src) but still am getting this error.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm running this on localhost

Comment: Is it the typo in the file name firebase-messagin-sw.js? => firebase-messaging-sw.js?